# Pass Excel value into multiple methods of same class

Tags: excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-dataprovider

I'm using selenium and Java to create my automated scripts. I need one help from you all.

I have an excel which contains 5 columns - say names are Col1 , Col2 , Col3 , Col4, Col5.

I have a class.

```
public class testone{

    @Test(Dataprovider="test")
      public void methodone(String Col1) {
      }

    @Test(Dataprovider="test")
      public void methodtwo(String Col2, String Col3){
    }

    @Test(Dataprovider="test")
     public void methodthree(String Col4, String Col5){
    }

    @DataProvider(name="test")
       public Object[][] getData() {

        String sheetName = "headercomptests";
        int rows = excel.getRowCount(sheetName);
        int cols = excel.getColumnCount(sheetName);
        Object[][] data = new Object[rows - 1][cols];
        for (int rowNum = 2; rowNum <= rows; rowNum++) { 
                for (int colNum = 0; colNum < cols; colNum++) {
                                data[rowNum - 2][colNum] = excel.getCellData(sheetName, colNum,    rowNum);     }       }
       return data; } //end of dataprovider class
```

For now it throws error in all methods as the number of cols don't match the arguments. How can i get it as mentioned.

If the number of parameters match excel cols , it works.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do not over-complicate your code. Since your tests need **different** data, use two **different** data providers. One for each test method. Each data provider would provide its own set of  columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HashMap` in your `@DataProvider` and `@Test` method.

1. Update `DataProvider` to return `HashMap`

   ```
   @DataProvider(name="test")
   public Object[][] getData() {    
   Object[][] data = new Object[rows - 1][cols];

    for (int rowNum = 2; rowNum <= rows; rowNum++) 
    { 
      // Create Hashmap after every row iteration
      HashMap<Object, Object> testData = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
      for (int colNum = 0; colNum < cols; colNum++) 
      {
       //Assuming excel sheet has Col1 , Col2 , Col3 , Col4, Col5 as name in 1st row
        testData.put(excel.getCellData(sheetName, colNum, 0),excel.getCellData(sheetName, colNum, rowNum));     
      }
      // Add every row in hashmap
      data[r][0] = testData;   
    }
    return data; 
   }
   ```

Please update above code as per excel sheet for proper mapping with `HashMap`

2. Update all `@Test` methods by passing `HashMap` as parameter and then inside each `@Test` method, retrieve column values are per requirement :

   ```
   @Test(Dataprovider="test")
   public void methodone(Map<Object, Object> testData) {
    //Get value of column 'col1' from testData HashMap
    String Col1 = (String)testData.get("Col1");
   }
   ```